# Do I earn reputation for posts on Meta?

Tags: support, meta, reputation

Do I also earn reputation for posts on Meta?

I have a [post on here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8388/should-i-give-credits-to-reviewers-when-i-post-revised-code) that does earn some upvotes from time to time but it seems that I never earn reputation for it.

I tried to search in the Q&A if they contain some possible reasons, but I could not find anything then the reputation limit:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below

This wasn't really the case.

Comment: I've asked and answered a few meta questions, and have not received any rep. So I don't think you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't get any reputation on Meta, but you can actually get the [Mortarboard badge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard) for earning 200 reputation in one day.

So even though you don't get any reputation, you can actually get 200 of it in one day.

(The badge is rewarded as if reputation was given as normal, but no reputation is actually given)

Comment: did anyone ever earn this on meta?

Comment: @nath Click the link, 10 of us have earned it - myself included.

Answer (score 4):

ok I dare to write a self anser, since I just found the relevant text on [what is meta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is
>   the same as your reputation on Code Review Stack Exchange
>   (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have
>   5 reputation to participate on meta.

somehow I must have been skipping this part earlier.